# Unable to launch in macOS Catalina

Tags: osx, install

I recently upgraded my Mac to Catalina 10.15.6.

I also upgraded emacs to 27.1.  When I try to start it, I get an error: `"Emacs" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software`:

[image: that is cannot check for malicious software]

I tried downloading the dmg directly from emacsformacosx.com and installing via `brew cask install emacs`, which appeared to get it from the same place.

`brew install emacs` installed 26.3 and would only open it in the terminal, not as a separate app.  I know that there used to be a `--with-cocoa` option, but I could not figure out how to get that to work.

What do I need to do to install emacs on Catalina, such that it works in a separate window rather than in a terminal?

Comment: I don't think I have the full answer yet but some relevant material is:

* https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/87415 - suggests brew cask reinstall emacs --no-quarantine

* Having done that you will find that it can't open some files. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53248/finder-of-macos-catalina-cannot-open-a-file-with-emacs proposes a modification to Emacs.app to work around this.

* https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/12/12/fixing-emacs-macos-catalina/ is also worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Posting what worked for me from [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/87415#issuecomment-672338143)

`brew cask reinstall emacs --no-quarantine`

Comment: For some reason, this only worked on my machine with the `cask` and `reinstall` swapped around: `brew reinstall cask emacs --no-quarantine`

Comment: `brew reinstall homebrew/cask/emacs --no-quarantine` worked for me.

Comment: `brew cask` is no longer a brew command. The correct, updated command is now `brew reinstall emacs --no-quarantine --cask`as suggested by @Shahbaz Zaidi.

Answer (score 1):

This should resolve the issue

`brew reinstall emacs --no-quarantine --cask`

Comment: It would help to explain that line a bit - just what was changed and why it has the effect it does.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message, `"Emacs" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software` with Emacs.app v27.2-3 (the most recent version as of this writing), downloaded as disk image from https://emacsformacosx.com/  and installed on macOS Big Sur, Version 11.6.1. To work around this error, I downloaded and installed one of the older versions, [Emacs-26.3-universal.dmg](https://emacsformacosx.com/emacs-builds/Emacs-26.3-universal.dmg). The credit should go to *dahanbn*, who posted the workaround on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/jb8tf6/comment/g8u0dic/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) - please upvote there.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I installed it by downloading the dmg. So if you try `brew reinstall` you'll get:

> Error: It seems there is already an App at '/Applications/Emacs.app'

So, get into the Applications folder, delete the Emacs app. And then run `brew install` instead of `reinstall`:

`brew install emacs --no-quarantine --cask`

(I'm running BigSur, the command may be slightly different in other macOS versions)